# "There was an error completing your request" on Google Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

When trying to publish an app from DialogFlow from the integration section of the console.

After clinking "Manage Assistant App" or "Test" in the integrations > Google Home assist tab, I get the following Error:

> There was an error completing your request

The page is
https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/project/[projectname]/simulator/
or
https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/project/[projectname]/overview/

And, when I import my project into Google Actions, no actions show up.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the Error Message you get. I also reformatted the question. You should possibly add an [mcve] of your code so people with knowledge of the subject will be able to help you figure out what's wrong! Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: If you look at  this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HipsHUsSvjQ you can see simulator, but I'm just getting "There was an error completing your request"

Answer (score 0):

The description is too vague to help with this so here are some questions:

1. where from (from which screen) do you find and click the "Manage Assistant App"? Is this from the DialogFlow or the Actions on Google (AoG) dashboard?
2. Is your project working and providing the correct responses when you
   try it from the DialogFlow?
3. Are you using a fulfillment?
4. If yes do you use the inline editor?

If yes, here are 2 things that can provide you with more information about the issue:

1. At the DialogFlow 'try it now', check the JSON object that it responds with by clicking on the "Diagnostic info" and check for any errors
2. At the fulfillment, scroll at the bottom and click on the 'View execution logs in the Firebase console'

Comment: When you go to integration > google home assistant > INTEGRATION SETTINGS then hit Test or manage assistant app

Comment: Its coming up on the https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/project[project name]/simulator/ page

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked out the issue. I have two google accounts. My personal account and my work account. The issue is when I click "Manage Assistant App" or "Test" it open google Actions. This is a separate application to DialogFlow.

When I opens Actions it changes to my personal account, but DialogFlow is using my work account. So I changes google Actions to my work account...........

And Bingo!!!!!!!

It works!!!!!